# SQL query into LINQ in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

Please anyone can help me to write this sql query into Linq. i have tried..

this is my sql query

```
select  o.OrderID,o.Nature,o.Date,od.TotalPrice,os.OrderStatus,lo.FirstName,lo.EmailAddress,lo.PhoneNumber
from [dbo].[Order] o
    inner join [dbo].[tbl_OrderDetails] od on  od.OrderID = o.OrderID
    inner join [dbo].[tbl_OrderHistory] oh on oh.OrderID = o.OrderID
    inner join [dbo].[tbl_Login] lo on o.UserID = lo.UserID
    inner join dbo.tbl_OrderStatus os on oh.OrderStatusID= os.OrderStatusID
group by o.OrderID,o.Nature,od.TotalPrice,o.Date,os.OrderStatus,lo.FirstName,lo.EmailAddress,lo.PhoneNumber
```

and this is my try

```
public override orderDetailModel orderDetails(int id)
{
    var results = from o in obj.Orders
        join od in obj.tbl_OrderDetails on o.OrderID equals od.OrderID
        join oh in obj.tbl_OrderHistory on o.OrderID equals oh.OrderID
        join l in obj.tbl_Login on o.UserID equals l.UserID
        join os in obj.tbl_OrderStatus on oh.OrderStatusID equals os.OrderStatusID
        where (od.OrderID == id)
        group o by new { o.Nature, o.OrderID } into 
        select new orderDetailModel
        {
            OrderID = o.OrderID,
            OrderStatus = os.OrderStatus,
            Date = o.Date,
            DeliveryNature = o.Nature,
            EmailAddress = l.EmailAddress,
            FirstName = l.FirstName,
            PhoneNumber = l.PhoneNumber,
            TotalPrice = od.TotalPrice
        };
    //group o by new {o.OrderID};
    orderDetailModel data = (orderDetailModel)results.FirstOrDefault();
    return data;
}
```

but this is wrong query its not working fine please help me

Comment: "but this is wrong query its not working fine" What does this mean? Do you get errors? Is the query returning whrong elements? If so what did you expect instead?

Comment: i mean when i write group by code is show errors on select and o.orderID,so how can i put group by in this code?

Comment: Actually I cennot see any meaning in grouping by a `TotalPrice`?. However your grouping within LINQ seems quite different as this within SQL. Why do you write this `by new {...}` stuff?

Comment: Rather than use joins in Linq you really should try to use the Navigation Properties https://coding.abel.nu/2012/06/dont-use-linqs-join-navigate/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to correct the `group by` clause, like you have in the SQL query like this:-

```
group new { o, l } by new {  o.OrderID,o.Nature,od.TotalPrice,o.Date,os.OrderStatus,
                             l.FirstName, l.EmailAddress,l.PhoneNumber } into g
                      select new orderDetailModel
                      {
                          OrderID = g.Key.OrderID,
                          OrderStatus = g.Key.OrderStatus,
                          Date = g.Key.Date,
                          ..and so on
                      };
```

Since you need the grouping on two tables `Order` & `tbl_Login` you will have to first project them as anonymous type `group new { o, l }` then specify all the groupings and finally while projecting use `Key` to get the respective items.

Comment: Ohh Thank you Rahul its working for me i really need  this exactly

Answer (score 0):

I guess that actually, also the SQL query is not correct.
I would simply use a SELECT DISTINCT ... instead of Grouping all the columns.

Anyway, first thing to do:

1. Check if databases is designed correctly. As far as i can see, if you're joining the table with their Ids, i don't understand why you need to group all the data. If you have duplicates, maybe the error is in the Database design.
2. If you can't change your Database, or you are happy with it, then use the following LINQ approach:

   ```
   var distinctKeys = allOrderDetails.Select(o => new { o.OrderID, o.Nature, o.TotalPrice, o.Date,o.OrderStatus,o.FirstName, o.EmailAddress,o.PhoneNumber }).Distinct();

   var joined = from e in allOrderDetails
                join d in distinctKeys
                on new { o.OrderID, o.Nature,o.TotalPrice, o.Date,o.OrderStatus, o.FirstName, o.EmailAddress, o.PhoneNumber }   equals d select e;

   joined.ToList(); // gives you the distinct/grouped list
   ```